# Create PDF with three different elements (Chart, SVG, and Table) in single PDF page using JsPDF

Tags: pdf, .net-core, jspdf, html2canvas, html-to-pdf

> Here in HTML I have three things Chart, SVG, and Table. On button click I want to add all those three elements in one PDF. But I can add only svg and chart as image into pdf. I am facing issue while adding the table as HTML to pdf.

```
 <script>
        function saveAsPDF() {
            const pdf = new window.jspdf.jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            const htmlContent = $('#flooreMain')[0];
            console.log(htmlContent)
            pdf.html(htmlContent, {
                  callback: function () {
                    // Add image after HTML content is added
                    addImageToPDF(pdf);
                  },
                });
        }

        function addImageToPDF(pdf){
            html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {

                // Use jsPDF to create a PDF from the canvas
                //var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

                var pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
                var pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
                var imageWidth = canvas.width;
                var imageHeight = canvas.height;
                var ratio = imageWidth / imageHeight >= pageWidth / pageHeight ? pageWidth / imageWidth : pageHeight / imageHeight;
                var _canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                _canvas.setAttribute('width', 1080);
                _canvas.setAttribute('height', 1920);
                var ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 8, 1080, 1920);

                //ctx.drawImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg'), 'JPEG', 0, 8, imageWidth * ratio, imageHeight * ratio);
                pdf.addImage(_canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg'), 'JPEG', 0, 8, imageWidth * ratio, imageHeight * ratio);
          
                pdf.save('chart.pdf');
            });
        }
    </script>
```